# "session.id" unavailable on client side

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, cookies

I'm currently facing a problem in which I want to redirect the user back to the login page if the session cookie doesn't exist on the client side. For this I'm using Express and Vue-Router. In the routing itself I'm not facing any problem.

The problem is that if I type into the Chrome console (or call `console.log` inside Vue Routers BeforeEach):

```
document.cookie
> ""
```

It returns me an **empty string**, however, I certainly have a cookie stored on the client side, as seen in the "Request" Network tab and inside the "Cookies Tab"(?).

[image: Network Tab]

[image: Cookie Page Tab]

I searched on Google for 'connect.sid' (default session name according to the docs) and even renamed it into 'sess_id' to test. I removed the cookied and tried again, but I got nothing.

However, if I set a cookie *myself* inside Express, it appears inside `document.cookie`.

Am I not seeing something obvious?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Also, I'm using "express-session" for this on the serverside, if that matters.

---

I'm initializing it with:

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secret_!$A",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
    name: "sess_id"
  })
);
```

and creating a session inside my login route (serverside):

```
req.session.user = {};
req.session.user.id = "1234";
req.session.user.permissions = [ ... array ... ];
```

This creates the cookie as seen above. It's sent back to the server normally with every request and pages load normally. I just can't see it *myself* inside JS.

Comment: Is the `HttpOnly` flag set? Look near the end of the response header value.

Comment: @skirtle Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Per docs: "as compliant clients will not allow client-side JavaScript to see the cookie in document.cookie" That's probably it.

Comment: @skirtle httponly is set to "True".

Comment: Setting httpOnly to "false" made them available inside JS! I'm also aware of the security implications. I should have read the docs. Thank you! You can post this as an answer.